# Constructing a list of all three-element subset of a list

Tags: replacement, sequence

The list I have is

`{a,b,c,d,e}`

I would like to use `ReplaceList` to construct a list of three-element subset of the above list.

This would require the use of `BlankSequence` but I do not understand how it works.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen `Subsets[]`?

Comment: @Szabolcs I never thought it was a good idea but this came up in an as an exercise in mathematical physics.
Would you explain to me how BlackSequence works?

Comment: @Szabolcs It says "three element subset of the list {a,b,c,d,e}"

Comment: @Szabolcs It's sort of a prelude...I'm not new to Mathematica but there are stuffs like pattern matching and conditions which aren't something that a non-computer science student would be intimately acquainted with on a daily basis; hence, the bit of obstacles.

Comment: @J.M. I have. But how does this aid with determining all possible three-elements of a set/list?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
ReplaceList[{a, b, c, d, e}, {___, x_, ___, y_, ___, z_, ___} -> {x, y, z}]
(* {{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, b, e}, {a, c, d}, {a, c, e}, 
    {a, d, e}, {b, c, d}, {b, c, e}, {b, d, e}, {c, d, e}} *)
```

Comment: How does `BlankSequence` works? I've looked at the documentation but it isn't clearly explained.

Comment: @Physkid This is BlankNullSequence. I find the explanation in the documentation quite clear: "a pattern object that can stand for any sequence of zero or more Wolfram Language expressions". I am honestly not sure what more can be said, so the ball is in your court to explain why you are having trouble with it.

Comment: If you like it better that way: `___` will match any number of comma separated things.

Comment: What does it mean by 'Pattern object'?

Comment: You must read this: https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/patterns/ and this: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html in full before asking any more pattern related questions.

Comment: I tried experimenting with patterns. In an attempt to find the squares of three numbers from a list of numbers, I tried 
`ReplaceList[{6, 44, 30, 15, 24, 12, 33, 23, 18, 8}, 
 x_^2, +y_^2 + z_^2 -> x]`.
But strangely, I'm not being returned with a desired outcome.
The code is interpreted as "find all ways {6, 44, 30, 15, 24, 12, 33, 23, 18, 8} can be expressed as x_^2, +y_^2 + z_^2.